# http://localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/ is not working

Tags: django-admin

i got the Site matching query does not exist when i tried to open the django admin panel how to resolve this error . I think i missed some kind of declaration in the setting of the projects please guide what it can be ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please make sure path('admin/', admin.site.urls) present in <your_project>/urls.py file and 'django.contrib.admin' present in INSTALLED_APPS list in settings file